# sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score "cv" parameter question

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was working through a tutorial on the titanic disaster from Kaggle and I'm getting different results depending on the details of how I use `cross_validation.cross_val_score`.

If I call it like:

```
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, titanic[predictors], titanic["Survived"], cv=3)

print(scores.mean())

0.801346801347
```

I get a different set of scores than if I call it like:

```
kf = KFold(titanic.shape[0], n_folds=3, random_state=1)

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, titanic[predictors], titanic["Survived"], cv=kf)

print(scores.mean())

0.785634118967
```

These numbers are close, but different enough to be significant. As far as I understand, both code snippets are asking for a 3-fold cross validation strategy. Can anyone explain what is going on under the hood of the second example which is leading to the slightly lower score?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the sklearn [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) for `cross_val_score`'s cv argument :

> For int/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either
> binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases,
> KFold is used.

I believe that in the first case, `StratifiedKFold` is being used as the default. In the second case, you are explicitly passing a `KFold` generator.

The difference between the two is also documented in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation).

> `KFold` divides all the samples in $k$ groups of samples, called folds (if
> $k = n$, this is equivalent to the *Leave One Out* strategy), of equal
> sizes (if possible).
>
> [...]
>
> `StratifiedKFold` is a variation of `k-fold` which returns
> `stratified` folds: each set contains approximately the same
> percentage of samples of each target class as the complete set.

This difference in folds is what is causing the difference in scores.

As a side note, I noticed that you are passing a `random_state` argument to the `KFold` object. However, you should note that this seed is only used if you also set `KFold`'s shuffle parameter to `True`, which by default is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

[As mentioned by @Reii Nakano](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/14047/98307) if us estimator is classifier and your $Y$ is binary `StratifiedKFold` will be used else `KFold` will be used.

Also interesting part here is you are using `random_state = 1` in `KFold`. So data in splits in case of `KFold` is not necessarily same as `Splits` in `cross_val_score`.
Hence, your final score may differ.